# How to add GTM Codes in the Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, community, force.com

To integrate SF Community with Google Tag Manager, GTM provides two code snippets to be installed into 'head' and 'body' tag of the Community site. SF Community allows to install code-snippet into 'head' tag, but How to install second code-snippet into 'body' tag of the Community/Force.com Sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you need to create an empty HTML5 container in the Visualforce page.

example:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false"
           showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false"
           title="Unused Title">
<html>

    <head>
        <title>HTML5 Container Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- You can put your code snipet here. -->
        <h1>An Almost Empty Page</h1>

        <p>This is a very simple page.</p>
    </body>

</html>
</apex:page>
```

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_container_page.htm)